# How to load a tree on just active tab

Tags: performance, tabs, tree, extjs4.1, autoload

I have two tabs and both tabs have tree. Since the trees take time to load, I am only trying to load a tree on the active tab panel(tab1), but even with autoload: false on my tab2's tree store, my second panel's tree store gets loaded, which is making the tab panel slow to load. So I guess my question is how to optimize the speed of loading the tab. I am just trying to speed up the loading time. and also when I load both tab's store I get two layered "loading mask", which is obvious because it is loading the mask for both tab1 and tab2. Is there a different approach than just doing

```
autoLoad: false
```

on tab2's tree store?

Comment: Do you have a root node defined on the store with autoLoad: false set?  I vaguely remember having this issue too, if you can answer my question I can provide an answer most likely.

Comment: No Reimus, I don't have a root node defined in my tree. and I am postiive that the store is set to autLoad:false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered what I would almost consider an issue in Extjs.  The reason autoload: false is not working is that when you do not actually define the 'root' property in your store, the store creates a default root node with default properties that cause it to load (I'm guessing that you may have displayRootNode on the tree set to false also?).  The way to work around this is to keep the autoLoad property set to false and define the root node in the tree like this:

```
root: {
    id:       "0",
    expanded: true,
    loaded:   true
}
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly Reimius... :)... Thanks for clarifying this problem...